# $w(a+b) = w(a) + w(b) − 2w(ab)$ equality for $\mathbb F_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> If $a,b ∈ \mathbb F_2^n$, then $w(a + b) = w(a) + w(b) − 2w(ab)$.
>   How can I find equality for $\mathbb F_q^n$?

I tried to find something over $n=2$, but i found nothing.
has it found before or i am trying to find really hard thing?

Comment: Have you tried looking at $\operatorname{wt}(x-y)$ which is the _Hamming distance_ between $x$ and $y$ and tried relating it to your right side of your Hamming _weight_ formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For vectors $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb F_q^n$, *define* $x\otimes y$ as the vector whose $i$-th component is
$$(x\otimes y)_i = \begin{cases} x_iy_i, &\text{if } x_i =  y_i,\\0, 
&\text{if } x_i \neq  y_i.\end{cases}$$
Then, with $d_H(x, y)$ denoting the Hamming distance between $x$ and
$y$, and wt$(x) = d_H(x,0)$ the
Hamming weight of $x$, 
$$d_H(x,y) = \text{wt}(x-y) 
= \text{wt}(x) +  \text{wt}(y) - 2 \text{wt}(x\otimes y).$$
Turning to the question asked, we have that
$$\begin{align}
\text{wt}(x+y) &= \text{wt}(x - (-y))\\
&= \text{wt}(x) +  \text{wt}(-y) - 2 \text{wt}(x\otimes (-y))\\
&= \text{wt}(x) +  \text{wt}(y) - 2 \text{wt}(x\ominus y)
\end{align}$$
where
$$(x\ominus y)_i = \begin{cases} x_iy_i, &\text{if } x_i +  y_i = 0,\\0, 
&\text{otherwise. }\end{cases}$$